# Python, Asyncore and forks

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, asyncore

Just for starters, I used Twisted and SocketServer with both ForkMixIn, ThreadMixIn and tried the "thread-pool" recepies.

However, I wanted to make something particular work in Python.

Alittle background. Previously I wrote in C a simple TCP deamon that would bind to a socket and listen on it, then pre-fork X many times and then just pass the serversocket desc to all the forks and everyone would accept the clients very very marrily.

I checked out the "select/poll" based asyncore which I like alot. My only beef was that I could get a little CPU unbound by forking a few times to take advantage of the multi-cpu machine and hope for the best with scheduling.

I cant make it work for the life of me. Only 1 single instance can accept connections, all others simply throw an exception on handling the connect, 'can not iterate thru Empty'.

is this even feasible? I checked alot, but I couldnt find ANY code for forking asyncore dispatchers (cry)

Thank you!

**Update 1: (Full traceback as requested)**

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <__main__.EchoServer listening 0.0.0.0:8001 at 0x2ad4880c93f8> (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:'NoneType' /python2.6/asyncore.py|readwrite|99] [/usr/local/python2.6.9/lib/python2.6/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|408] [./6py-server.py|handle_accept|87])
```

Always happens in accept, regardless if I fork before the asyncore.loop, etc.

**Update 2: (full source)**
[pastebined source](http://pastebin.ca/1666012)

Comment: Could you update the question with exact traceback?

Comment: Done, and sorry for not doing it in the first place. Very silly of me.

Comment: Also added full source, just in case someone has the time and will to give this one a shot. Apologies for not including everything relevant from the get-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use code markup for traceback, otherwise it's displayed messed and we don't see exception type.

But I believe it's `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` since `self.accept()` can return `None`. The reason is that several processes can get read event for listening socket, but only one can accept it. The rest processes will get `EWOULDBLOCK` error which is caught, but then it returns `None` instead of connection-address pair.

Change your `handle_accept()` to return immediately when `accept()` returns `None`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Try on accept and return on it. Thank you!
Большое спасибо моему Московскому коллеге :)